# Bounce rate query is time sensitive beyond expectation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Bigquery.
I am trying to find bounce percentage for each app version. A bounced user is defined as a user who first launched the app in the selected date range, then removed the app (in the selected date range) after using the app only once, i.e. a single session.

Here is my code:

```
with launched as (
select distinct user_pseudo_id as total_distinct_users
FROM `table-app.analytics_317927526.events_*` 
where 

user_pseudo_id in (
 SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id
 FROM `table-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
 WHERE 
 event_name = 'first_open'
 AND event_date
 BETWEEN    
@DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
))
 
,
demo_launched as
(SELECT 
          user_pseudo_id,
          --country
          --operating_system,
          --device_brand,
          --device_model,
          --os_with_version,
          app_info_version
          --traffic_source_name
          --language
          
      FROM table-app.churn_analysis.user_demographics
where user_pseudo_id in (select * from launched)
)
,


removed as (
select distinct user_pseudo_id as total_distinct_users
FROM `table-app.analytics_317927526.events_*` 

   WHERE user_pseudo_id IN (
   SELECT distinct user_pseudo_id
   FROM `table-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
   WHERE event_name = "app_remove"
     AND event_date
   BETWEEN  
   @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
 
 )
 AND event_name = 'first_open'
 AND event_date
 BETWEEN    
@DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE
)
 
,
counts as(
select user_pseudo_id,  count(event_name) as event_countss
    from `table-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
    where event_name='session_start'
    and user_pseudo_id in (select * from removed)
    group by user_pseudo_id
)
,
dataset as 
(select distinct user_pseudo_id from counts where event_countss=1)

,
demo_bounced as
(SELECT 
          user_pseudo_id,
          --country
          --operating_system,
          --device_brand,
          --device_model,
          --os_with_version,
          app_info_version
          --traffic_source_name
          --language
          
      FROM table-app.churn_analysis.user_demographics
where user_pseudo_id in (select * from dataset)
)
,
group_launched as (
select app_info_version ,count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as launched_users
from demo_launched
group by app_info_version)
,
group_bounced as (
select app_info_version ,count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as bounced_users
from demo_bounced
group by app_info_version
order by bounced_users desc
--limit 10
)
,
final as (
select group_launched.app_info_version,  group_bounced.bounced_users ,round((bounced_users/launched_users)*100) as percentage_bounced
from group_launched
right join group_bounced 
on group_launched.app_info_version=group_bounced.app_info_version
)

select * from final
where app_info_version<>'null'
order by final.bounced_users desc
```

Here is the problem: lets say version 2.0 was launched on October 17, 2023. When in the code above, I put start date as 1 October 2023 and end date as 17 January 2024 - the bounce percentage for version 2.0 is significantly higher than if I put the start date as 1 January 2023 and end date as 17 January 2024. Why is this?

Comment: This is difficult to troubleshoot without sample data, not to mention a lot of CTEs here. You could have a one-to-many join somewhere and/or something else is wrong. I would start with one CTE, then add another, etc and look at counts returned (and compare to table data) until you identify the issue.